# How to filter tweets based on input location's boundary box (City, country, area) in tweepy API python

Tags: python, twitter, location, tweepy

I am trying to filter the tweet stream based on both input keyword and location (variables).

If I want to filter tweets based on keyword and a certain location, locations parameters in line below

```
myStream.filter(track=keywords_to_track, locations=boundary_box)
```

should be a boundary box with four coordinates of the input location (maxlog, minlog, maxlat, minlag)

how to get boundary_box for a given location(variable)?
or
is there any other way to solve this issue?

I have also tried https://www.mapdevelopers.com/geocode_bounding_box.php, but it's not working.

I am new to tweepy API.

```
# arguments
topic_name = 'kafkatwitter_1'

#input variables
keywords_to_track = ['modi']
location_filter = 'New Delhi'

# twitter authorization
auth = OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_KEY_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)

# init tweepy
api = tweepy.API(auth)
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                         value_serializer=lambda x: dumps(x).encode('utf-8'),
                         api_version=(0, 10, 1))
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.Stream):
    def on_status(self, tweet):
        length = len(tweet.text.split(' '))
        if (tweet.lang != 'en') or (length <= 10):
            pass
            print("==filtered==")
        else:
            message = {
                "text": tweet.text,
                "created_at": process_time(tweet.created_at),}
        producer.send(topic_name, value=message)
# Step 2: Creating a Stream
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)

# Step 3: Starting a Stream
myStream.filter(track=keywords_to_track, locations=boundary_box)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Nominatin API](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/#parameters)

Search parameters include:

- street=<housenumber> <streetname>
- city=<city>
- county=<county>
- state=<state>
- country=<country>
- postalcode=<postalcode>

Example:

```
GET https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?city=Tokio&format=json&limit=1
```

Response includes **boundingbox**:

```
[
    {
        "place_id": 282632558,
        "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
        "osm_type": "relation",
        "osm_id": 1543125,
        "boundingbox": [
            "20.2145811",
            "35.8984245",
            "135.8536855",
            "154.205541"
        ],
        "lat": "35.6828387",
        "lon": "139.7594549",
        "display_name": "Tokyo, Japan",
        "class": "boundary",
        "type": "administrative",
        "importance": 0.7593311914925306,
        "icon": "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

https://boundingbox.klokantech.com/

`[-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8]` is a location box for San Francisco.
`[-74,40,-73,41]` is a location box for New York City.
`[-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8,-74,40,-73,41]` are location boxes for San Francisco and New York City.

Assign that to the variable `boundary_box`.
The `locations` parameter expects and array of floats. Amount of floats is dividable by 4.